# The Mathematic of finding the Decay Product Compoistion of Pitchblende/Uraninite

Tags: radioactivity

Just as the title says.  I’m curious as to how you would go about figuring out the amount of decay products in a given sample of Pitchblende/Uraninite.  I would hazard a guess at using the half life formula over and over but something seems off about doing that.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can analyse a sample and immediately *know* the composition. Do you want to derive a former composition, e.g. at 10 million or a billion years ago?

Comment: He may not immediately know, some decay products will be in trace amounts and some will be very transient.

Comment: Karl:  I trying to figure out what a given sample day 10kg or so of Pitchblende would contain in terms of decay products.  I.e. the element composition of Pitchblende as of today assuming it was made when the earth was formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is straightforward. You get the amount of radioactive compounds in your mineral. Then find out the decay chain reactions, it generally goes from Uranium to Lead.

http://metadata.berkeley.edu/nuclear-forensics/Decay%20Chains.html

[image: example for U-235]

Then you will find half-life constants for each reaction and start to calculate from U-235 to lead one by one.

Well if you think that it is just chore, write a Fortran code and enter radioactive decay constants, reactions and make a user input chain part and everyone can calculate the decay products for a given mineral/time.

Comment: Ah.  That was my original method.  But wouldn’t that be incorrect? Taking the half life of Uranium-235 over the existence of the Earth or said material would get you the remaining amount of Uranium-235.  Then using the difference in masses that would be the Thorium generated.  Now doing the half life equation again for thorium makes it sound like it would be like tacting on another existence of Earth or said material.  Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't get what is incorrect, and "would be tacting on another existence of Earth or said material".
Radioactive decay rate is independent of the amount of material, find the production of Th and removal of Th in a unit time, then multiply it with (start-end)/unit time.
Maybe that is more proper. Apply it with all remaining chain.

Comment: If you found the half life for a kilo of uranium-235.  And then when to find the amount of the thorium that has decayed in said time span, wouldn’t that be like repeating the same timespan but for new material?

Comment: Nope, what I said was this. U-> Th -> Pa, let says U halves itself in 1 billion year, Th does it for 500 million.
10 kg U reduces 5 kg in 1 b year, assume nearly 5 kg Th, but in that span Th halves itself twice, and (5kg/2)/2 = 1.25 kg remained. 
So it is produced 5 kg and decayed 3.75 kg in 1 b, net 1.25 kg generated. Then you will just multiply it with 4.5 to find what left after 4.5 billions year, 5.625 kg Th is the answer.

Comment: I know good sir.  But what I’m saying is when you use the half life equation on thorium, the time used in the equation is it the same time interval as the uranium on or a different one

Comment: All the elements have different half-lifes. If you understand previous question you must know this Dalis, and the following equation:
[generation rate(Th)] = [decay constant (U)]*[time]
 [decay rate(Th)] = [decay constant (Th)]*[time]
[accumulated amount (Th)] = [time]{[decay cont.(U)]-[decay const.(Th)]}
Here all [time] are 4.5 billion years. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Ok I will call defeat on answering the question.  I would need a whiteboard to explain it better.  I will use my original method